# Order of values changes when concatenating two Pandas Series

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have a list features_reduced which is as follows:

```
Index([u'NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG.1', u'NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG', u'NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG', u'NE.IMP.GNFS.ZS', u'NY.GDP.DISC.CN', u'FS.AST.PRVT.GD.ZS', u'FS.AST.DOMS.GD.ZS', u'NY.GDS.TOTL.ZS', u'NY.GDP.DISC.KN', u'NY.GDP.NGAS.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.PETR.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.COAL.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.TOTL.RT.ZS', u'MS.MIL.XPND.GD.ZS'], dtype='object')
```

The second list is as follows:

```
data_2yr.columns[0:4]
Out[295]:
Index([u'LogdiffT', u'Year', u'Country', u'SW'], dtype='object')
```

I am concatenating them:

```
features=data_2yr.columns[0:4]|features_reduced
```

However it is changing the order of values in the list and gives something like this

```
features
Out[296]:
Index([u'Country', u'FS.AST.DOMS.GD.ZS', u'FS.AST.PRVT.GD.ZS', u'LogdiffT', u'MS.MIL.XPND.GD.ZS', u'NE.IMP.GNFS.ZS', u'NY.GDP.COAL.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG', u'NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG.1', u'NY.GDP.DISC.CN', u'NY.GDP.DISC.KN', u'NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.NGAS.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG', u'NY.GDP.PETR.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDP.TOTL.RT.ZS', u'NY.GDS.TOTL.ZS', u'SW', u'Year'], dtype='object'
```

First of all: Why is that happening. In a normal list of strings, if I do the same operation it would retain the order. Why it is reshuffling the order here. 
If I do a similar thing with normal list below, it retains the order.

```
l=["a","b","c"] +["m","e","f"]
l
Out[299]:
['a', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'e', 'f']
```

So why is it behaving different for Pandas series.

And secondly how to rectify it without having to do some sorting etc. I want in the same order as they appear in each series

EDIT:

Ok I have figured out a solution:

```
features=list(data_2yr.columns[0:4])+list(features_reduced)
[u'LogdiffT',
 u'Year',
 u'Country',
 u'SW',
 u'NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG.1',
 u'NY.GDP.PCAP.KD.ZG',
 u'NY.GDP.DEFL.KD.ZG',
 u'NE.IMP.GNFS.ZS',
 u'NY.GDP.DISC.CN',
 u'FS.AST.PRVT.GD.ZS',
 u'FS.AST.DOMS.GD.ZS',
 u'NY.GDS.TOTL.ZS',
 u'NY.GDP.DISC.KN',
 u'NY.GDP.NGAS.RT.ZS',
 u'NY.GDP.PETR.RT.ZS',
 u'NY.GDP.COAL.RT.ZS',
 u'NY.GDP.MINR.RT.ZS',
 u'NY.GDP.TOTL.RT.ZS',
 u'MS.MIL.XPND.GD.ZS']
```

But why does it happen if I don't convert them to list?

Answer (score 0):

`|` does not concatenate; it takes the union, which may have an unexpected order.  To concatenate, use [`pandas.concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve here.  You seem to be using pandas Index objects without any accompanying Series, which, while possible, is usually not particularly useful.

Answer (score 0):

The `pandas.Index` is not a list. As the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html) says it is an "Immutable ndarray implementing an ordered, sliceable set". Using the `+` operator creates the set union of them, which as seems does not guarantee a preserved order. When you convert them to lists you do normal list concatenation using `+`.